# Increase Interval Gap In NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I m new in iPhone development. I've one NSMutableArray.

```
arrayNo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"10",@"50", @"100", @"1000 ",@"2000", @"5000", @"10000",nil];
```

but now, what I want to do is the interval gap between this values is not in perfect difference.after reaching 10000,i want to increase this array by 10000 interval. Eg. 10000, 20000, 30000 up to N number.

I'm displaying this number in UIPickerView.

Comment: Is this still unsolved?

Answer (score 2):

As you have a mutableArray, filled with few values and only after 10000 you need to fill with stepping by 10000.

```
arrayNo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"10",@"50", @"100", @"1000 ",@"2000", @"5000", @"10000",nil];
```

Now do it as :

```
for(NSInteger num=20000; i<=N ; i+=10000){ //N is your last number
    arrayNo[arrayNo.count]=@(num);
}
```

**But keep the range of Integer or long long int in consideration**

Comment: It's an array of strings, not `NSNumber`s.

Comment: It's an array of  NSNumbers

Comment: That's not important. He will still need to produce the numbers to get this done. He can convert to strings on the way in or out of the array.

Comment: If it is String use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",num];`